# Javascript (or JQuery) Long String Search and CSS insert help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a solution to search for a string from a partly dynamically generated page created in a third party system and apply a CSS string.
The closest solution I have found that might help to do the job is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('*').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 255, 255)" 
    }).css('background-color', '#000')
});
```

However, I need this modified to search for this string:

```
    <div class="ls-wrapper ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;
```

then, effectively insert a new CSS string into the same element style sheet so the resulting code behaves like this would:

```
    <div class="ls-wrapper ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; **new-css: property;** margin-left: 0px;
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single selector string: take the tag definition's HTML:

```
div class="somethingElse ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;"
```

and turn it into a selector string:

```
div.ls-wrapper.ls-in-out[data-slide-index="1"][style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;"]
```

(The prefix-less `div` indicate a tag name; the dot-prefixed substrings indicate a class; the string immediately inside a `[` indicates the attribute name, and the value inside the quotes indicates the attribute value.)

Simply pass that to jQuery, and then you can set the `css` appropriately, no need for `.filter`:

```js
$('div.ls-wrapper.ls-in-out[data-slide-index="1"][style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;"]')
  .css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ls-wrapper ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;">foo</div>
<div class="somethingElse ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;">bar</div>
<div class="ls-wrapper ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;">baz</div>
```

Technically, you could also achieve this with CSS alone, using the same selector string, not sure if that's flexible enough for your purposes though:

```css
div.ls-wrapper.ls-in-out[data-slide-index="1"][style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="ls-wrapper ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;">foo</div>
<div class="somethingElse ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;">bar</div>
<div class="ls-wrapper ls-in-out" data-slide-index="1" style="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;">baz</div>
```

If the `style` contains *more* stuff after the string you described, instead of `style="`, use `style^=` to check that the `style` attribute *starts* with the desired string:

```
div.ls-wrapper.ls-in-out[data-slide-index="1"][style^="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! That looks great, but, I can't get your initial answer to work in my particular case because there is a bunch of dynamically generated CSS properties that follow on after the margin-left: 0px; property. These additional properties are animated and actively change regularly. Is it possible to overcome this problem by using a wildcard on the selector after margin-left: 0px ?

Comment: @Dez try `$('div.ls-wrapper.ls-in-out[data-slide-index="1"][style^="z-index: 116; margin-left: 0px;"]')` The `^` means starts with

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("ls-wrapper ls-in-out");
    var $elem = $(element);
    //here I'm checking if the element exists and if the data-slide-index property == 1
    if($elem.length === 1 && $elem.data('slide-index') === 1){
        $elem.css('background-color', '#000');//add new css here
    }
});
```

instead of matching the entire string, I'm searching for the class name "ls-wrapper ls-in-out". The first element found is returned. Then I'm checking if the data-slide-index attribute has a value of 1. If all these are verified, then you can add your custom css

Comment: Thank you again for your answers. Regarding the Jquery and CSS answers: They work ok in a JSFiddle box but for some reason (I can't find) they don't work in my php generated page.Is it possible to add a little more targeted matching to these? For example, check these matches upto 3 parents in a nest of elements?     Regarding the Javascript answer: The "style="z-index: 116" property would also need to be included in the matching list because multiple instances of "ls-wrapper ls-in-out" with "data-slide-index="1"" are present in the page.

Comment: Got it to work... eventually. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I Apologize I couldn't respond earlier. Did you end up adding more targets?

Comment: Hi, No. Not to your script. The dynamic page generator was preventing all these scripts from running.